# MYSQL case when error when tried to get value based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql, case

Why I am getting error with this query ?  Is there something I'm missing ?

So I wanted to get online_date if the "via" field is O, then if the "via" field is M I wanted to get the manual_date

```
SELECT a.seqreq,
b.idfieldb ,
c.idfieldc ,
a.number_given,
case upper(a.via) when 'O' then 'Online'
when 'O' then 'Online'
when 'M' then 'Manual'
else a.via
end as via,
case when upper(a.via) when 'O' then a.online_date
when 'M' then a.manual_date //it says error on this line ?
else a.others_date
end as date_registered
from mytablea a 
left join tbl_b b on a.idfielda=b.idfieldb
left join tbl_c c on a.idfielda=c.idfieldc
left join tbl_d d on a.userEntry=d.NoIdUser
```

the error message :

```
W (1): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'when 'O' then
```

Comment: `case when upper(a.via) when 'O' then a.online_date`  => `case  upper(a.via) when`

Comment: Thanks Serg! How dumb i am didn't see that coming :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some syntax error in query. An comma(,) is missing after `a.seqreq`. In second `case` statement it will be `case  upper(a.via) when 'O' then a.online_date` instead of `case when upper(a.via) when 'O' then a.online_date`.

```
SELECT a.seqreq,
b.idfieldb ,
c.idfieldc ,
a.number_given,
case upper(a.via) 
when 'O' then 'Online'
when 'M' then 'Manual'
else a.via
end as via,
case  upper(a.via) when 'O' then a.online_date
when 'M' then a.manual_date 
else a.others_date
end as date_registered
from mytablea a 
left join tbl_b b on a.idfielda=b.idfieldb
left join tbl_c c on a.idfielda=c.idfieldc
left join tbl_d d on a.userEntry=d.NoIdUser
```

Comment: Thanks Kazi didn't see that one :3 Gosh embarassing